# Circular(radial,bandish) Lines appearing in render and rendered mode

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

[image: Circular(radial,bandish) Lines appearing in render and rendered mode]

So occasionally I keep seeing lines like so, its hard to recreate the problem. I've tried messing with textures layer overrides.

If you look closely there are bands at the center of the view a like a vignette.

The lighting is from the world with AO checked set to Factor 1 and Distance 5. I'm not sure the cause but tampering with visible layers, masking and exclusion seems to send it away.

Just curious if any one has faced this or where its coming from.

Sorry cant share the blend file as its for work.

Comment: Color banding or quantization errors. It is possible that your monitor cannor accurately display the subtle changes in tones. Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74809/rendered-image-shows-visible-line-strokes-artefacts

Comment: Thanks will try messing with the dither if it comes up again.