# Is banding in solid view normal?

Tags: color

If I set up a cube in solid mode and put the view inside it, I see what looks like a lot of banding:
[image]

If I up the contrast, it's a lot easier to see:

[image]

Is this normal limitations-of-8-bit, is it a blender problem, or could it be a graphics driver problem?

I realize it doesn't look like a lot of banding on the screenshot, but it's far more noticeable when panning around.

### Edit in response to duplicate

This is not in rendered images (at least that I can tell), just in the viewport.

Comment: there is no way to escape banding on 8 bit displays You can try dithering the rendered images. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5795/what-does-dither-do-in-cycles/5800#5800

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rendered image shows visible "line strokes" artefacts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74809/rendered-image-shows-visible-line-strokes-artefacts)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137459/blender-2-8-cycles-denoiser-produces-banding/137471#137471 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6488/spotlight-with-halo-applied-is-creating-rings-around-light/6489#6489

Comment: @susu Thanks, none of the questions you linked helped, afaik those are about rendered images, this seems to just be in the viewport. As for the bit on 8 bit displays, how do I tell if it's just that usual 24-bit color limitation or if there's something else going on?

Comment: 255 tones is not enough to resolve subtle changes on values that are similar.

Comment: Rendered image is dithered by its natural process. But view port do the rendering directly and without sampling or sample far less from final render. Then banding effect will become highly noticeable. (Also view-port might use 6-bit for faster rendering perhaps)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I don't know how to totally fix it, but I learned that if you choose 16bit in output it looks a little bit better, also to set 2.0 in dithering in post processing.