# Strange Color-Banding Problem

Tags: color, file-format, color-management

The color-banding is only in the image when saved from blender.
I screenshot the render and it has almost no color-banding.
How can I have no color-Banding when Saving from Blender?

the images were too big so they are drive links

Render.png (https://drive.google.com/file/d/132FNi4RITUSi9AQbE7WmcaqUTBgcqfew/view?usp=drive_link)

Render.exr (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MKKZtpsu-Dh1IUg1zVZEelAXNx27Tu8Q/view?usp=drive_link)

Screenshot (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FImKST7hTYPgR70u2k52ciERZgSIb7kv/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: Did you try to set *Color Depth* to *16 bit*? You can find it under `Output Properties > Output` if you set the *File Format* to *PNG*. For *OpenEXR*, try *Float (Full)*.

Comment: yes I on the png the color depth is 16 and the exr is float Full

Comment: It seems that 16 bit is the highest PNG can support, and [the general suggestion is to use OpenEXR](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153805/how-do-i-export-a-render-as-a-png-with-a-color-depth-of-32-bit). Since you're not satisfied with the OpenEXR output, I think you need to use another solution to get rid of banding. Dithering is a good option. The image I uploaded [here](https://we.tl/t-FSHmhJQevc) was dithered in GIMP. I assume that the screenshot uses compression or something that breaks up the banding. Without more information I can't tell for sure.